# sh script not getting executing from cron

Tags: macos, shell, cron

I am trying to execute a shell script from cron. I am running on Mac 10.15.6 .

However it is not getting executed. Below is my command

[image]

Right now the shell script just have some echo statements which should have got printed into the  output.log

Output.log is created but does not have any contents .So, it seems the shell script is not getting executed at all.

I have made the script executable by executing chmod +x.

Also i don't see the sh executable in /usr/bin/sh . Could this be the cause ?
But the shell script is getting executed through the command line..

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: check what is the shell running on your machine , using the command : echo $SHELL . Modify your cronjob using that shell. for example if it shows /bin/bash then modify your cronjob by replacing sh with /bin/bash.

Comment: thanks for the reply ...echoing gave /bin/bash..i replaced sh with /bin/bash in the crontab. but having the same behaviour

Comment: lets see if the script is throuwing any error  by re-directing stderr also to stdout . add **2>&1** between your script name and  >>   symbol in your cronbob. check if output log is showing any errors or entries

Comment: dont give any shell at all in crontab entry . */5 * * * * /Users/<*****>/git/SimpleTests/org.saurav.simpletests/test.sh >> /Users/<*****>/git/SimpleTests/org.saurav.simpletests/output.log

Comment: @confusedgenius thanks my sh script is working...i am trying to execute a mvn command through my script....but its not working...i have setup the appropriate path variables in the beginning of shell script